# using data-attribute inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have table rows and each of them has an `ID`. How can I use `data-attribute` to button `EDIT` if my code look like this?

```
//some javascript code

var content = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success edit_shipment" data-id="b.booking_id">Edit</button>';
return content;

//some javascript code again

//when Edit onclick, it shows modal
$('#booking_table tbody').on('click', 'button.edit_shipment', function(){
 $('#edit_shipment_modal').modal('show');
```

`data-id="b.booking_id"` is not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the use of the data attribute in your code ?

Comment: i want to show edit form on modal, so i need `id` from each row @AymDev

Comment: You need multiple `ids` in your data-attribute ? If the ids come from other elements, you better get the elements in an array, then loop through it to insert each id in another array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery-Method `attr();` You pass the name of the attribute as a string parameter. It than returns the value of the given attribute.

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/TobiObeck/8g6kxxow/

Answer (score -1):

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Comment: why downwote on my answer?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.